# Amazon Device Messaging is crashing runtime, on android emulator, how to fix it?

Tags: android, amazon-device-messaging

**Almost all the answers available on stackover, I have already tried in last 5-6 hours, please don't mark duplicate :)**

I have referred [Amazon Device Messaging documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/overview.html) for integration into my android project, everything compiles fine but when I run this project it crashes with a message

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Stub! You are bundling a stubbed jar in the apk! Please move it to the classpath instead.
```

I have use the approach **"Gracefully Degrade If ADM Is Unavailable"** by marking in AndroidManifest.xml like below

```
<!-- You must explicitly enable ADM. You must also declare whether your application will run with or without ADM.
        If you specify android:required="false", your app must degrade gracefully when ADM is unavailable. -->
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging"
            android:required="false" />
```

Also, inside file MainActivity i am checking the availability of ADM like the below code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //some other codes here
    boolean admAvailable = false;
    try {
        Class.forName( "com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM" );
        admAvailable = true ;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Handle the exception.
    }
    if(admAvailable) {
        ADMManifest.checkManifestAuthoredProperly(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

[Github link of my demo app](https://github.com/sheshnathiicmr/ADM/tree/master)

Comment: Did you get any solution to that? I'm having this issue too.

Comment: Yes, with help from my android developer friend I got this worked, I placed amazon SDK in some other folder not in the project, as this should be a reference only should not include in project/apk

Comment: Did you update your github repo ? Can you please tell me a little more detail about it ?

Comment: Github repo is not updated, will write as my answer

Comment: Okay, waiting for the answer

Comment: Hello @Sheshnath, i am waiting for the answer

Comment: bro! Please share your solution, im really trapped.